# JSpinner Increment Calendar.MINUTE by 15

Tags: java

I'm trying to increment my `JSpinner` by 15, 30 and 45 using `SpinnerDateModel`. I tried to pass the value in constructor in the fourth argument which `int calendarField` as `Calendar.MINUTE + 15` but this gives me even the field is `int`.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid calendarField

Runnable class below.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;


public class Spinner extends JPanel 
{
static String[] columnNames = {
    "Value"
};
static Object[][] data = {
    {"07:00 AM"}
};
public static void main( String[] args ) throws ParseException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);

    TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
    TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(0);
    tc.setCellEditor(new NewClass.SpEditor());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(table);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


private static class SpEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{
    JSpinner spinner;
    JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor;
    JTextField textField;

    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

    public SpEditor() throws ParseException 
    {
        super(new JTextField());
        spinner = new JSpinner();
        spinner.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(date.parse("07:00 AM"), date.parse("07:00 AM"), date.parse("07:00 PM"), Calendar.MINUTE + 15));
        spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "hh:mm a"));
        editor = ((JSpinner.DateEditor)spinner.getEditor());
        textField = editor.getTextField();


    }
    // Prepares the spinner component and returns it.
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column
    ) {
        return spinner;
    }

    // Returns the spinners current value.
    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return spinner.getValue();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The detail about ***invalid calendarField*** are within the `SpinnerDateModel.class` where it does this:

```
if (!calendarFieldOK(calendarField)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid calendarField");
}
```

and which has its implementation as:

```
switch(calendarField) {
    case Calendar.ERA:
    case Calendar.YEAR:
    case Calendar.MONTH:
    case Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR:
    case Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH:
    case Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH:
    case Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR:
    case Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK:
    case Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH:
    case Calendar.AM_PM:
    case Calendar.HOUR:
    case Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY:
    case Calendar.MINUTE:
    case Calendar.SECOND:
    case Calendar.MILLISECOND:
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

I hope that explains the exception you're getting. Since there is no case for `27`(MINUTE+15) in the implementation.

Comment: I see what I got this error. So it's not possible to increment it by 15?

Comment: @Francisunoxx In case you are looking to implement a custom increment and decrement, you probably need to implement your own `SpinnerModel` as also stated as an answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090502/how-do-i-know-if-increment-decrement-on-jspinner-is-pressed?rq=1